# Forum software for elgg?

Tags: forums, elgg

We have an elgg site, and need to have forum functionality.
The forum should be community wide and not focused on groups, 
as the standard installation comes along.
We need single-sign-on for the site.

My research so far:

- There's a phpBB3 plugin, I'd love to
  see phpBB3, but that breaks the reqs:
  no single-sign-on available yet.
- vanilla forum plugin
- vazco_forum plugin

Any suggestions? Vazco seems to be working, but is quite basic in functionality. Haven't had a look at vanilla so far. Other possibilities?

Thanks

Comment: Seems better suited to serverfault.com or superuser.com to me

Answer (score 1):

Found the light weight fluxbb forum integration by Team Webgalli. We have purchased a licence for our site. So far its working fine as they advertised. We now have got more than 1000+ threads in this forum. The plugin is really recommended. Its including an elgg style theme also. 
http://webgalli.com/pg/groups/1325/fluxbb-forum-integration-for-elgg/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module that changes the links and titles for the groups forum making it seem like it's a community wide forum instead of groups based. This approach might work for you.